# Why won't the loop stop iterating?

Tags: java, loops, do-while, tic-tac-toe

I am a beginner java student writing a gui tic-tac-toe program for my class. (No players, just computer generated).

Everything in my program works as expected, except for one thing; it seems that the placement of my method call for `checkWinner` is not place correctly, because the assignment for the X's and O's always finish. Why won't the loop end as soon as there is a winner?

It will return the correct winner based on the method call, but the for-loop will continue to iterate and fill in the rest (so sometimes it looks like both the x and o win or one wins twice). I've been going crazy, thinking it might be the placement of my `checkWinner` method call and if statement. When I set the `winner = true;` shouldn't that cancel the loop? I have tried putting it between, inside and outside each for-loop with no luck :(

I have marked the area I think is the problem **//What is wrong here?//** off to the right of that part the code. Thank you for any input!! :)

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    int total = 0, i = 0;
    boolean winner = false;


    //stop current game if a winner is found
    do{

      // Generate random # 0-1 for the labels and assign 
      // X for a 0 value and O for a 1 value

      for (int row = 0; row < gameboard.length; row++) //rows
      {
        for (int col = 0; col < gameboard[row].length; col++) //columns
        { 

          //Generate random number
          gameboard[row][col] = (int)(Math.random() * 2);  

          //Assign proper values
          if(gameboard[row][col] == 0)
          {
            labels[i].setText("X");
            gameboard[row][col] = 10; //this will help check for the winner
          }

          else if(gameboard[row][col] == 1)
          {
            labels[i].setText("O");   
            gameboard[row][col] = 100; //this will help check for winner
          }             


          /**Send the array a the method to find a winner
            The x's are counted as 10s
            The 0s are counted as 100s
            if any row, column or diag = 30, X wins
            if any row, column or diag = 300, Y wins
            else it will be a tie
            */

          total = checkWinner(gameboard);      **//Is this okay here??//**
          if(total == 30 || total == 300)        //
            winner = true;                //Shouldn't this cancel the do-while?


          i++; //next label

        }
      }//end for
    }while(!winner);//end while



    //DISPLAY WINNER
    if(total == 30)
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X is the Winner!");
    else if(total == 300)
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "0 is the Winner!");
    else
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It was a tie!");
  }
```

Comment: Sidenode: What happens if no winner is found? Game will restart (while not aborted), so your "tie" option is never possible.

Comment: Try printing a message to System.out when you set your `winner` flag to `true`; make sure it is actually happening.

Comment: You don't need to initialize `total` with zero, because it will be overwritten by the `checkWinner` result. However you need to initialize `i` with zero, AND you should do that INSIDE a `do` loop before `for(row)`.

Comment: @JasonC I did what you said using JOption and what happens is that it pops up as soon as someone wins, however, after I press okay, the same message continues to pop up until the end of the loop.

Comment: @dognose It does work if their is a tie. If I can edit my code post I will add the checkWinner method if anyone wants to see it. However, I do not think it has to do with my current issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your code iterates through a board and generates random marks of X and O. This leads to some very odd board states, being always filled row-by-row, and possibly with unbalanced number of X and O marks.

IMHO you should organize your code in opposite manner to fill a board similary to a true game. I mean a series of 9 marks 'XOXOXOXOX' spreaded over the board.

Let `Labels labels` be a nine-character array, initialized to 9 spaces.

```
public int doGame( Labels labels)
{
    labels = "         ";
    int itisXmove = true;              // player X or O turn
    for( int movesLeft = 9; movesLeft > 0; movesLeft --)
    {
        int position =          // 0 .. movesLeft-1
                (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * movesLeft);

        for( int pos = 0; pos < 9; pos ++)        // find position
            if( labels[ pos] == " ")              // unused pos?
                if( position-- == 0)              // countdown
                {
                    if( itisXmove)                // use the pos
                        labels[ pos] = "X";       // for current player
                    else
                        labels[ pos] = "O";
                    break;
                }

        int result = checkWinner( labels);        // who wins (non-zero)?
        if( result != 0)
            return result;

        itisXmove = ! itisXmove;                  // next turn
    }
    return 0;                                     // a tie
}
```

then

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    Labels labels;

    int result = doGame( labels);

    if( result == valueForX)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X is the Winner!");
    else if( result == valueForO)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O is the Winner!");
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It's a tie!");

    for( int rowpos = 0; rowpos < 9; rowpos += 3)
    {
        for( int colpos = 0; colpos < 3; colpos ++)
            /* output (char)label[ rowpos + colpos] */;

        /* output (char)newline */;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some improvement: a player cannot win until he/she makes 3 moves, so we may conditionally call `checkWinner` when `movesLeft` is less than 5. Additionally we needn't check the whole board – the winning three must be in a row or in a colum or in a diagonal where the current move was done. And of course the winner can only be the player who made the current move. So `checkWinner` routine should get `labels` and `pos` parameters, fetch the label from `labels[pos]` and compare it to two, three or four pairs of other positions, depending on the `pos` value. Then return that label or zero.

Answer (score 2):

The *easiest* way would be to break all loops at once. (Even if some people dont like this)

```
outerwhile: while(true){

  // Generate random # 0-1 for the labels and assign 
  // X for a 0 value and O for a 1 value

  for (int row = 0; row < gameboard.length; row++) //rows
  {
    for (int col = 0; col < gameboard[row].length; col++) //columns
    { 

      total = checkWinner(gameboard);     
      if(total == 30 || total == 300)        
        break outerwhile;  //leave outer while, implicit canceling all inner fors.


      i++; //next label
    }
  }//end for
}//end while
```

This However would not allow for the "tie" option, because the while will basically restart a game, if no winner has been found. To allow tie, you dont need the outer while at all, and can leave both fors at once, when a winner is found:

```
  Boolean winner = false;
  outerfor: for (int row = 0; row < gameboard.length; row++) //rows
  {
    for (int col = 0; col < gameboard[row].length; col++) //columns
    { 

      total = checkWinner(gameboard);     
      if(total == 30 || total == 300){        
        winner = true;     
        break outerfor;  //leave outer for, implicit canceling inner for.

      }

      i++; //next label
    }
  }//end for

  if (winner){
    //winner
  }else{
     //tie.
  }
```

Comment: If you find the label + `break` unpalatable, an alternative is to do `while (!winner)` and add `&& !winner` to the inner for loop conditions.

Comment: Even better would be to think about what this code is doing in the first place, and not have all these breaks. The original code looks like it is simply updating labels and replacing numbers in the game board, which is an action that should not affect the "winner" state. It would make more sense to loop through and update the labels, to *not* do the 0->10 and 1->100 replacement, and simply check for a winner once afterwards.

Comment: I tried these both, however my output will never get passed the first three labels. No matter how many times I press the new game button.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking the value of `winner` until both `for` loops complete. Add a `break` right after you set `winner = true`, and add an

```
if (winner)
{
    break;
}
```

to the beginning or end of your outer `for` loop.

Comment: he is checking, its inside the inner loop. Just the output is after the while.

Comment: @JasonC It most certainly will prevent the `for` loops from terminating when there's a winner. The value of `winner` will be set to `true` within the inner `for` loop, but the `while` condition won't be checked until both `for` loops complete.

Comment: @dognose He is setting the value of `winner` inside the inner `for` loop but he is not checking that value until after the `while` loop completes an iteration. As written, in order for the `while` loop to complete an iteration both `for` loops must run to completion.

Comment: IF the function `checkWinner()` is implemented correctly, it should always return true, after a winner condition is met. Therefore the while should exit, after the fors have completed all remaining fields - which should not turn the game from "theres a winner" to "theres no winner".

Comment: @dognose Yeah, that's the problem, right? If you read the OP you'll see that he wants the `for` loops to terminate as soon as there is a winner.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your do/while statement is wrapped around the `for` statements. So the `for` statements end up running their entire cycle before it ever reaches the `while` statement. A solution to get around this is checking for a winner in the `for` statements and breaking:

```
//stop current game if a winner is found
do {

    for (int row = 0; row < gameboard.length; row++) //rows
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < gameboard[row].length; col++) //columns
        { 

            // ... your other code ...

            total = checkWinner(gameboard);
            if(total == 30 || total == 300) {
                winner = true;
                break; // end current for-loop
            }

            i++; //next label
        }

        if (winner) break; // we have a winner so we want to kill the for-loop
    } //end for

} while(!winner); //end while
```

So you should be able to just loop through the two for-statements and break upon a winner. Your code also does not seem to handle a tied case, but I am guessing you already know that.

Comment: @dognose That's not the desired behavior though. The op wants the game to end as soon as there's a winner, not after all the fields have been filled.

Comment: @MikeB, no I just had the second break statement in the wrong place so it would not have worked properly. Dognose was correct, but I edited my post.

Comment: 1) You can add `!winner` to the `for` continuation condition: `for (int col = 0; col < gameboard[row].length && !winner; col++)` 2) You can add a label in front of the first for and `break` to that label: `WINNER: for (int row = 0; row < gameboard.length && !winner; row++)` and `break WINNER;` 3) Now that you know how to break to a label, you can even make the `while` loop infinite and `break` it without using a boolean.

Comment: I tried this, however my output never gets past the first line on the tic-tac-toe grid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your loop condition and add one more bool.

You have a "tie" condition but currently you only check for winner. The only explanation without the checkWinner code is that you are encountering a tie every time.

So...

```
boolean tie;
boolean winner;

do {
//your stuff
}
while(!(tie || winner))
```

Edit: I didn't realize you put the while loop outside your for loop, you will need to break out of your for loops in order for the while condition to be checked.

```
//stop current game if a winner is found
    do{

      for (int row = 0; row < gameboard.length; row++) //rows
      {
        for (int col = 0; col < gameboard[row].length; col++) //columns
        { 
            if(winner || tie)
                break;
        }//end for

        if(winner || tie)
            break;
      }//end for
    }while(!(winner || tie));//end while
//the rest of your stuff here
```